# After calling WCF from javascript showing ServiceName not define

Tags: javascript, asp.net, wcf

In my local system every thing working fine.Problem started when i deployed into server. Tried many things no luck. Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
            <Services>
                <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/Services/WebChatWCFService.svc" />
            </Services>
        </asp:ScriptManager>

WebChatWCFService.ClientRecieveMessage(vSno, TokenNo, UpdateMessageSuccessCallBack, UpdateMessageFaileCallBack);
```

Error is : **WebChatWCFService** is not defined.

This is my webconfig section:

```
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="WebChatWCFServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
      <enableWebScript />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="Ileverage2k10.Services.WebChatWCFServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
<services>
  <service name="Ileverage2k10.Services.WebChatWCFService" behaviorConfiguration="Ileverage2k10.Services.WebChatWCFServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="WebChatWCFServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Ileverage2k10.Services.WebChatWCFService" />
  </service>
</services>
```

In my WCF : Namespace :Ileverage2k10.Services

```
 [ServiceContract(Namespace = "",
            SessionMode = SessionMode.Allowed)]
        [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
        public class WebChatWCFService
        {
             [OperationContract]
            public List<DClientTempDataContract> ClientRecieveMessage(int vSno, int vTokenNo)
            {
                List<DClientTempDataContract> result = new List<DClientTempDataContract>();

                List<dclienttemp> messageList =
                    LinqClinetFilter.ClientReceiveMessage(vSno, vTokenNo);

                foreach (dclienttemp msg in messageList)
                {
                    result.Add(new DClientTempDataContract(msg));
                }

                return result;

            }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue due to extensionless URL handlers in IIS which results in the web service fail to recognize.
Please refer to the solution in the below link.
https://support.microsoft.com/zh-cn/help/2520479/web-services-may-fail-on-microsoft-internet-information-services-iis-7
Besides, there is a workaround for this problem. we could use the completed URL to replace the relative address during the registration of the service in the ScriptManager control.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
            <Services>
                <asp:ServiceReference Path="http://localhost:56697/Content/CostService.svc" />
            </Services>
        </asp:ScriptManager>
```

Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: Great help thank you. Got to know about extensionless url. Found out i did't activate the HTTP Activation for WCF Services. It's working fine now.